# EF Core migration loop

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, many-to-many, entity-framework-migrations

I have a simple many to many relation defined between the `Course` and `Student` entities

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

I configured both entities to use `my_schema` database schema

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
     .ToTable(nameof(Student), schema: "my_schema");

 modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()
     .ToTable(nameof(Course), schema: "my_schema");
```

After running the generated migration, database tables are generated as expected
[image: database diagram]

Autogenerated join table has the same schema as tables it is related to. And this is causing the poblems.
 Each new migration will now include strange (and useless) `RenameTable` operation:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.RenameTable(
        name: "CourseStudent",
        newName: "CourseStudent",
        newSchema: "my_schema");
}

protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.RenameTable(
        name: "CourseStudent",
        schema: "my_schema",
        newName: "CourseStudent");
}
```

I am using EntityFramework Core version 5.0.2.
I see in generated Snapshot migration file that `CourseStudent` entity maps to table without specifying the schema

```
modelBuilder.Entity("CourseStudent", b =>
    {
        b.Property<int>("CoursesCourseId")
            .HasColumnType("int");

        b.Property<int>("StudentsStudentId")
            .HasColumnType("int");

        b.HasKey("CoursesCourseId", "StudentsStudentId");

        b.HasIndex("StudentsStudentId");

        b.ToTable("CourseStudent");
    });
```

With this information missing, I suppose, the tool generating new migrations is stuck in a loop where it is changing the schema for join table, but forgetting to note this somewhere (snapshot). Or am I missing something?
I know there are some workarounds, I just want to know if this is a bug or my incorrect implementation.
Thank you

Comment: Liiks like an issue.  Can you post a repro here?: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues  You should be able to work around by making CourseStudent an entity and configuring its schema.

Comment: Sure, I will post it there

Comment: [Issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/23937)